# Sorted List, implementation file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sortedlist

So I am working on a problem and this is given information but for whatever reason it wont compile. I copied exactly from a textbook and I get errors in the implementation file such as const (a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function) and value(member is not accessible). I am guessing it is just a simple typo or or something included at the top but i cant figure it out.

```
 //  SPECIFICATION FILE  ( itemtype.h )

const  int  MAX_ITEM = 5 ; 
enum  RelationType { LESS, EQUAL, GREATER } ; 
class  ItemType   // declares class data type
{       
   public :     //  3 public member functions
     RelationType    ComparedTo ( ItemType ) const;
     void Print() const;
     void Initialize(int number);
   private:
      int value;
};
//  IMPLEMENTATION FILE  ( itemtype.cpp )
//  Implementation depends on the  data type of value. 
  #include  “itemtype.h” 
  #include  <iostream> 
  using namespace std; 

 RelationType ComparedTo ( ItemType  otherItem )  const 
 {      
   if  ( value  <  otherItem.value )   
        return  LESS ;  
   else  if ( value  > otherItem.value )   
        return  GREATER ;  
   else  
        return  EQUAL ; 
 }  
 void Print ( ) const  
 {  cout  <<  value  <<  endl ;
 }
 void Initialize ( int  number ) 
 { 
   value  =  number  ;               
 }
```

Comment: you need to tell the method implementations that they belong to a class. For example  "RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo ( ItemType  otherItem )  const" instead of "RelationType ComparedTo ( ItemType  otherItem )  const"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities: either your book is wrong, or you didn't copy the code *exactly*.

When member functions are defined outside of the class definition, you need to tell the compiler which class they belong to:

```
RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo(ItemType otherItem)  const 
{
     // ...
}

// ...

void ItemType::Print() const
{
  // ...
}
```

and so on.

(There is no relationship between the class, the header file, and the implementation flie from C++'s point of view.)